# C3560CX-8PT-S UPOE

Tags: cisco, power-over-ethernet

I have a C3560CX-8PT-S sitting in the office which I know little about.

It states that it can be powered by the wiring closet switches.

Would anyone with experience in using UPOE to power switches be able to offer any advice, please?

Many thanks in advance,

Jason

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Catalyst WS-C3560CX-8PT-S is a PD/PSE product, which means that the switch can behave like both a Power Device (PD) and Power Source Equipment (PSE). This switch will be powered on by the PoE voltage derived from its uplink ports `Gi0/9` and `Gi0/10` or both at the same time. It can also be combined with the voltage supplied by the external auxiliary power supply (AUX).

At the time of writing Cisco UPOE is available on Cisco Catalyst 4500E Series and Catalyst 3850 Series Switches to power your compact switch. This means you can connect and power your switch via cable, minimum Category 5E, to a Cisco 4500E with a UPOE line card or Cisco 3850 with builtin UPOE.

Its important to know, that your particular switch can also be powered by either PoE or PoE+, if you wish to do so. The available PoE on the switch itself will only be 20W though (for 2 x PoE+).

When your compact switch is powered via UPOE you can use the command `show env power` to check the available power:

```
Switch# show env power
Power Source    Type        Power(w)    Mode
--------------  --------------  ---------   ---------
A.C. Input  Auxilliary  80(w)       Available
Gi0/9       Type2       30(w)       Available
Gi0/10      Type2       30(w)       Available

Available : The PoE received on this link is used for powering this switch and
providing PoE pass-through if applicable.
```

You can see on the below table, how much PoE is available, when your switch is power via PoE:

[image]

The following will show the comparison between UPOE and PoE:

[image]

More info:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960cx_3650cx/software/release/15-2_4_e/configurationguide/b_1524e_consolidated_3560cx_2960cx_cg/b_1524e_consolidated_3560cx_2960cx_cg_chapter_0111.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The `C3560CX-8PT-S` switch can be powered by POE through a single POE uplink or a dual POE uplink.

So the switch doesn't need an external power supply and it will also benefit from the UPS of the uplink switch.

Additionally the switch can perform POE-pass-through, I.E. power POE devices while being itself powered by POE.

From the [datasheet](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-3560-cx-series-switches/datasheet-c78-733229.html)

> PoE pass-through
>
> PoE pass-through gives the ability to power PoE end devices through
>   drawing Cisco UPOE from the wiring closet. The Cisco Catalyst
>   3560CX-8PT-S has eight downlink ports with two Cisco UPOE input ports
>   that allow it to be powered by another switch. These switches do not
>   need a power supply and receive power over the uplink from an upstream
>   PoE or Cisco UPOE device, providing deployment flexibility and
>   availability.

So it seems that the C3560CX-8PT-S must be powered by a UPOE device to be able to provide POE pass-through, which is logical since standard POE provide "only" 30W of power and the switch itself (max) power consumption is around 20W.

If connected to two UPOE uplink the switch can draw up to 120W of power (2x60) and consume up to 21.3W

This leave up to 100W to power other devices.

Note that the switch can be connected to an external power supply and in this case it can provide 146W.